# Rails how select a id on a array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 
model color

```
has_many :colorships
has_many :products, :through => :colorships
```

model product

```
 has_many :colorships
 has_many :colors, through: :colorships
```

on product controller i would like by select choose a color

```
def new
  Product.New
  @dropdown = @product.color_ids.collect { |co| [co.name, co.id] } 
end


def show
  Product.find(params[:id])
 color = product.color_ids.select { |i| [i.id] } 

end
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @EliSadoff select a id on a array

Comment: If by "id on an array" you mean index of the element within an array you want to use "each_with_index".  If you mean find the id of a record returned by Active Record, you can call the method "id" on the object (record) returned.

Comment: We would need to see your Product Model. Does product have many colors? And your User Model, does it just have one color?

Comment: @nzajt right is fixed thank's

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using has_many which will always return an array. You are doing a few things wrong.

Don't do `product.color_ids.nil?` because it will never be nil, you want `product.colors.empty?` because an empty array is not nil it is empty.

This line `current_user.find_by_color_id(product.color_ids.nil? ? nil : product.color_ids.color.id)` will never work. `current_user` is a Devise method to get the current_user object, so adding find to it will throw an error.

Also `product.color_ids.color.id` isn't going to work either. I am not sure what you are trying to do here but `product.colors` and `product.color_ids` will both return an array. If you want the first id you could do `product.colors.first.id` or `product.color_ids.first`.

It looks like you are a long way from home, sorry. I am happy to help more, but I would need more information, I would need the user model and an understanding of what your were trying to do with `current_user.find_by_color_id(product.color_ids.nil? ? nil : product.color_ids.color.id)`.

Comment: thank you very much. your are right. i'm trying to on product show the user get the selected color of the product. that's i'm trying to do.

Comment: so, the only way to get the id of array is just by the first id?